# How can I remove the last character of a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a file path as a string and trying to remove the last '/' from the end.

```
my_file_path = '/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/flask-auto/myDirectory/scarlett Johanson/1448543562.17.jpg/'
```

I've been trying it with regex but it just keeps removing all the '/'. Is there any easier way to just remove the last character without regex?

Comment: `stringvar[:-1]`

Answer (score 46):

The easiest is

as @greggo pointed out

```
string="mystring";
string[:-1]
```

Answer (score 40):

As you say, you don't need to use a regex for this. You can use [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip).

```
my_file_path = my_file_path.rstrip('/')
```

If there is more than one `/` at the end, this will remove all of them, e.g. `'/file.jpg//'` -> `'/file.jpg'`. From your question, I assume that would be ok.

Answer (score 5):

Answering the question: to remove the last character, just use:`string = string[:-1]`.

If you want to remove the last '\' if there is one (or if there is more than one):

```
while string[-1]=='\\':
    string = string[:-1]
```

If it's a path, then use the `os.path` functions:

```
dir = "dir1\\dir2\\file.jpg\\"   #I'm using windows by the way
os.path.dirname(dir)
```

although I would 'add' a slash in the end to prevent missing the filename in case there's no slash at the end of the original string:

```
dir = "dir1\\dir2\\file.jpg"
os.path.dirname(dir + "\\")
```

When using abspath, (if the path isn't absolute I guess,) will add the current working directory to the path.

```
os.path.abspath(dir)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `String.rstrip`.

```
result = string.rstrip('/')
```

Answer (score 3):

For a path use os.path.abspath

```
import os    
print os.path.abspath(my_file_path)
```

Comment: `os.path.abspath()` will also turn all forward slashes into backslashes on Windows platforms, so it may not always be the right solution.

Comment: except if  the real goal is having a valid path (even on windows)

Comment: You're right. It's a path. I was thinking it was an URL for some reason. `abspath()` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use slice.
If x is your string variable then x[:-1] will return the string variable without the last character.
(BTW, x[-1] is the last character in the string variable)
You are looking for

```
my_file_path = '/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/flask-auto/myDirectory/scarlett Johanson/1448543562.17.jpg/'
my_file_path = my_file_path[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last character, just use a slice: `my_file_path[:-1]`. If you only want to remove a specific set of characters, use `my_file_path.rstrip('/')`. If you see the string as a file path, the operation is [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname). If the path is in fact a filename, I rather wonder where the extra slash came from in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use expensive `regex`, if barely needed then try-
Use `r'(/)(?=$)'` pattern that is capture  last `/` and replace with `r''` i.e. blank character.

```
>>>re.sub(r'(/)(?=$)',r'','/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/flask-auto/myDirectory/scarlett Johanson/1448543562.17.jpg/')
>>>'/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/flask-auto/myDirectory/scarlett Johanson/1448543562.17.jpg'
```